# how can i change the color of my blocks

Tags: python, pygame

i want to know how i can change the color of the black blocks that are used so the player does not fall through the world.

im posting that code i think pertains to it, if you need more please tell me

i want them to be green like my backround color just a little darker i know how do the color, just dont know where i g to  change it because the blocks are black and i dont see them defined as a color anywhere

```
class Block:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.width = 32
       self.height = 32

    def render(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))



gravity = -0.5

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (50,60,200)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player(0,0)

# 25 colums and 19 rows
level1 = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]

blockList = []

for y in range (0,len(level1)):
    for x in range (0,len(level1[y])):
        if (level1[y][x] == 1):
            blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paramaters for `pygame.draw.rect` are `(Surface, color, Rect, width=0)` so you need to adjust the second parameter in order to have the color that you desire on whatever rectangle you are drawing at the time. You can modify your `Block` class like so:

```
class Block:
    def __init__ (self, x, y, color = (0,0,0)):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = 32
        self.height = 32
        self.color = color

    def render(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
```

This will default to black unless you pass it whatever other color. I'm not sure I understood where you want the blocks to be green, but wherever that is the case you just need to pass the color variable that you want into the block that you are creating.

Comment: wow im dumb i knew that just i was looking for black not 0,0,0

Comment: happens to everyone ;)

Comment: do you know how i can change it to a image? i think that will look nicer